# Integer multiplication using recursion nlogn runtime

Tags: python, recursion

Hi ive been stuck in this problem for some time now and i cant figure it out.
I need to write a recursive algorithm which multiplies 2 numbers in nlogn runtime.
Im not allowed to use mathematical expressions such as -,*,/,//,%.
I can only determine if the number is odd and divide by 2 with no remainder.
any suggestions would help

Comment: People write papers on such algorithms. These require peer-review to check the validity of them. This looks like it is outside of SO's scope. [This](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02070778/document) was a paper that caught the attention of a lot of mathematicians / computer scientists.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hint: if `y` is even, then `x * y = (x * 2) * (y // 2)`. If `y` is odd, then `x * y = x + x * (y - 1)`